# Is there a feature in VS code, to open a parent component AKA the component that is passing down props?

Tags: reactjs, search, visual-studio-code, components, react-props

I want to find a parent component, jump up the chain, without having to globally or ctrl+p to find keywords.

Answer (score 2):

The "peek" function shows files that use your component on the right sidebar.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_peek

On my Mac I use CMD+click, but here's the documentation:

> When you execute a Go to References search (via ⇧F12), or a Peek Definition (via ⌥F12), we embed the result inline:
>
> [image]